# HTML5 File Upload (How to select multiple files in Single browse click)

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I am looking for a jquery plugin with no ajax upload, the only feature that i am looking for is allowing the user to select multiple files after clicking browse, and not limited to choose one file in a single browse?

I have tried multi file upload http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/
but the user should browse for each file separately; i.e users are not able to select multiple files at the same time?

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the Fluid Infusion Uploader. The online demo is [here](http://fluidproject.org/releases/1.4/demos/uploader/demo.html). For more details, have a look at the [API documentation](http://wiki.fluidproject.org/display/fluid/Uploader+API).

Comment: but in this API, i can only upload the files using AJAX, right? what i want is for the files to be posted with a whole form using $_FILES, is that possible?

Comment: It allows uploads using `$_FILES`. Have a look at https://github.com/fluid-project/image-gallery to see how to build your php file.